# How to use "equalTo" with list of values in Firebase?

Tags: firebase

I have some data

```
{
  "1": {
    "result": 303
  },
  "2": {
    "result": 307
  },
  "3": {
    "result": 703
  },
  "4": {
    "result": 909
  },
  "5": {
    "result": 909
  }
}
```

So I can get *result* field of *3* key:

```
ref.child("3").once("value", (snapshot) => {
  const data = snapshot.val();
  console.log(data.result);
});
```

But I want to get array of *result*s of *3*, *4*, *5* keys in one query. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firebase currently doesn't support multiple `equalTo()`s.
This will get you an Array of 3, 4 and 5 but it just retrieves the last three:

```
ref.limitToLast(3).once("value", function(snapshot) {
    const data = snapshot.val();
    console.log(data.result);
});
```

otherwise i think you'd have to fetch all results and filter on your own.

something like this:

```
ref.child('posts').child('test').once("value", function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            if (childSnapshot.key() == 3 || childSnapshot.key() == 4 || childSnapshot.key() == 5) {
                data.push(childSnapshot.val().result);
            }
        });
        console.log(data);
    });
```